# dynamic binding of data to the dropdown list in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a view in which I am entering two different dates, So i want that all the entries in the database between these two dates should be displayed in a drop down list.
How can I do this?????

Answer (score 0):

From you controller return list of entries between these two dates like

```
enteries.Where(a => a.startdate < FirstDate &&  a => a.enddate < SecondDate  ).ToList()
```

and then pass these entries to DropDownListFor like

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.entryID,
    new SelectList(model.entries, "ID", "Title"))
```